# Gaussian Curvature of a Level surface

Tags: differential-geometry, surfaces, curvature

How can I compute the Gaussian curvature of a level set of the form $S =\{(x,y,z)\in\mathbb R^3 : f(x,y,z) = 0\}$? The particular example I'm looking at is $$f(x,y,z) = e^z\cos x - \cos y.$$ I wanted to find a global parametrisation of the surface but I don't think one exists.

Comment: That's true. How does that help?

Comment: I'm sorry I don't see how that makes it any easier to parametrise.

Comment: Perhaps [this old question and answer](http://math.stackexchange.com/q/433910/71348) will be of assistance.

Comment: use $(x,y)\mapsto(x,y,\ln\frac{\cos y}{\cos x})$ as a Monge's chart

Answer (score 1):

You will find an explicit formula [here](http://mathworld.wolfram.com/GaussianCurvature.html)